# Copy/Paste Plain text without the formatting

Tags: ios, iphone

i have to copy/paste text from Safari and Notes to the Mail App multiple times per day. Previous IOS update only pasted plain text without any formatting, but they changed it now.

Every time i paste text in the Mail App it comes with the formatting which is not what i need. I am familiar with COPY from the "Share" button. But, it would be much easier if there was a way to change something in settings to paste text without formatting using the regular copy/paste buttons?

Answer (score 1):

1. Quickly tap anywhere on the text field of the text you want to
   copy.
2. Choose Select All from the contextual menu.
3. Choose Share from the contextual menu.
4. 4-ChoseCopy from the Share Sheet.

[Source](https://wolfewithane.com/mastering-ios-pasting-plain-text-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

In desktop Mail App there is an option to delete formatting if you can use desktop for that. Method i use on phone is that i'm just pasting it into search and copying it again.